# Prove $f=1+x+x^2+x^3+\cdots+x^n$ has no multiple roots.

Tags: polynomials, proof-verification, roots

Prove $f=1+x+x^2+x^3+\cdots+x^n$ has no multiple roots.

My attempt:

Consider the polynomial $g=(x-1)(1+x+x^2+x^3+\cdots+x^n)$

As $f\mid g, g$ all the roots of $f$ are roots of $g$.

This means I have to prove the statement:

If $c$ is a multiple root of $f \Longrightarrow c$ is multiple a root of $g$.

Equivalently:

If $c$ is not a multiple root of $g \Longrightarrow c$ is not a multiple root of $f$.

I'll try to prove this last statement:

Suppose $\exists c$ such that $c$ **is** a multiple root of $g$, then

$$g(c)=0 \implies g'(c)=0$$

$$
g=(x-1)(1+x+\cdots+x^n) \implies  g'=nx^n
$$
$$
g'(c)=nc^n=0 \implies c=0
$$
But 
$$
g(0)\neq 0
$$
And we've found the contradiction: $\not \exists c: g(c)=g'(c)=0$. Then $f$ has no multiple roots.

Is this correct?

Also: Assuming this is correct, is it possible to prove $\sum_{k=0}^n \frac {x^n}{n!} $ has no multiple roots in a similar manner?

Comment: You could be clearer about what you know at each point and what you have to prove. When you write, "If $c$ is not a multiple root of $g \Longrightarrow c$ is not a multiple root of $f$," you have already proved that statement. What comes after is _not_ a proof of "this last statement," but rather a proof that for all $c$, $c$ is not a multiple root of $g$ (which you need in order to complete the entire proof). Also be careful of details; for example you wrote $g(c)=nc^n$ when you surely meant $g'(c)=nc^n$.

Comment: Yes, that's true (the example, I'll fix it). I understand what you mean by that I already proved that statement, but how can I phrase it? I'm sorry, some of the proof-writing is being troublesome to me. Thanks!

Comment: $f\mid g$ gives you that all roots of $f$ are roots of $g$ with at least as great multiplicity. So, "This means I have to prove the statement" can be replaced by "Therefore". Rather than "Equivalently," you might consider saying that you are about to do a proof by contradiction, starting with the assumption that there exists $c$ such that $c$ is a multiple root of $f$. Show that this implies that $g(c)=g'(c)=0$. You already have shown you can derive a contradiction from that statement;   the part from $g=(x-1)(1+x+\cdots+x^n) \implies  g'=nx^n$ to the end looks like it does this fine.

Comment: Minor correction, $g'(x) = (n+1)x^n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your proof is correct. Here is an alternative.

We have $f(1) = n+1$, so $1$ is not a root, and similarly, $f(0) = 1$, so $0$ is not a root.

Since $f(x) = {1 -x^{n+1} \over 1-x}$, if $x$ is a root of $f$, then $x^{n+1} = 1$, so just need to show that
$f'(x) \neq 0$ whenever $x^{n+1} = 1$.

Since $f'(x) = {1 -x^{n+1} \over (1-x)^2} - (n+1) {x^n \over 1-x }$, we see that
$f'(x) = - (n+1) {x^n \over 1-x } \neq 0$ whenever $f(x) = 0$.

For your other question, it is not clear what you mean by a similar manner.

Let $f_n(x) = 1+x+ {x^2 \over 2!}+\cdots+{x^n \over n!}$. We note that
$f_n(0) = 1$, so $0$ is not a root. Then we have
$f_n(x) = f_n'(x)+ {x^n \over n!}$, and so if $f_n(x) = 0$, we must have $f_n'(x) \neq 0$, hence any root is simple.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I was mostly asking if my proof was correct...

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: @copper.hat Not sure, this seems really petty.

Comment: @CameronWilliams: I'm not sure why it irks me so much given that I accept upvotes without question :-).

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD: I added a proof of the question at the end of your question.

Answer (score 3):

All roots of $f(x)$  also are  roots of $(x-1)f(x)= x^{n+1}-1.$ Since    $x^{n+1}-1$ is coprime  with its derivative $(n+1)x^n$  then $x^{n+1}-1$ has  no multiple roots. Thus and $f(x)$ has no multiple roots.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just talking about real roots, it depends on the value of n:
If n is odd, the root is -1 but if n is even, no real roots exist.

However if you are talking about all possible roots, then there exist exactly n roots, no matter the value of n. The roots of these particular equation are commonly referred to as the nth roots of unity